# gitlab: How to have a another gitlab-ci.yml and use it whenever i want, instead of automatic triggering

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file, which gets triggered when I commit changes.

I want to have another file `gitlab-ci-notrigger.yml` which will not be triggered. But I can use this to run pipeline whenever i want manually

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create a job than must be run manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually)

> You can require that a job doesn’t run unless a user starts it.
> This is called a **manual job**.
>
> You might want to use a manual job for something like deploying to production.
>
> To specify a job as manual, add [`when: manual`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#when) to the job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.
>
> By default, manual jobs display as skipped when the pipeline starts.

The OP adds:

```yaml
# WANT deploy-to-stage TO BE RUN ONLY WHEN automatic
deploy-to-stage:
  stage: staging
  script:
    -..........
```

Check if [using `except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) can help:

```yaml
# WANT deploy-to-stage TO BE RUN ONLY WHEN automatic
deploy-to-stage:
  stage: staging
  rules:
    - except: manual
  script:
    -..........
```

Comment: But then i dont want certain jobs not to be run, when i run manually

Comment: @Santhosh You can define a dedicated job which will run manually and will not call your other jobs (that you do not want to run when you trigger manually that dedicated job)

Comment: I have edited my question. and in the below added what i want. Can you tell me how to achieve that

Comment: @Santhosh OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: what about things which we want to run both at automatic and also manual times

Comment: I prefer to have two yml files. Both i can run manual, But only one of them will run automactically

Comment: I have edited my question. I think i cant achieve what i want in single file.